# How make a responsive input field in navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this navbar and an input field in the navbar. I want to set the width of input to all remaining width of the navbar. And It should be **responsive**. I mean to say that the input width should be changed when the device size changed. Please help me out.

```css
li {
list-style: none;
}
.post-edit .nav-header {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    height: 40px;
}

.post-edit .nav-header ul li button {
    border: 1px solid #727272;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #727272;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 3.5px 8px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 5.3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">  
    <!-- Main Container -->
    <main class="container-wrapper">
    
      <div class="post-edit">
        <form action="" method="post">
          <div class="nav-header navbar navbar-expand-sm">
            <!-- Left -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <input type="text" name="p-title" placeholder="Title">
              </li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Right -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <button class="nav-link">Preview</button>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <button class="nav-link">Publish</button>
              </li>              
            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
      </form>
  </div><!-- /.post-edit -->
  </main> <!-- /Main Container -->  
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please also include the rest of your CSS that applies to the nav bar code you have included (e.g. that puts Preview & Publish inside the nav bar).

Comment: i see that you are using bootstrap 3, upgrade to bootstrap 4 and they have a whole section about navbars https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/. however to answer your question, just use bootstrap grids system for achieveing the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise that you upgrade to bootstrap 4 and above so you can get helper and utility classes to make your work easier.

here is how you can achieve it with bootstrap 4. you can just restyle it back to bootstrap 3 if you want or use legacy css3.

- step 1: change the display of the wrapping container to flex-box
- step 2: set all the child elements to flex grow 1, which tells the child element to stretch and take up the entire remaining space of the parent element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 4px;
            margin-top: 2rem;
        }

        li {
            list-style: none;
        }

        .post-edit .nav-header {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            height: 40px;
        }

        .post-edit .nav-header ul li button {
            border: 1px solid #727272;
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #727272;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 3.5px 8px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            margin-top: 5.3px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
        <!-- Main Container -->
        <main class="container-wrapper">

            <div class="post-edit">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="nav-header navbar navbar-expand-sm d-flex">
                        <!-- Left -->
                        <ul class="navbar-nav bg-primary flex-grow-1">
                            <li class="nav-item flex-grow-1 mr-1 ">
                                <div class="bg-success d-flex flex-grow-1">
                                    <input type="text" name="p-title" placeholder="Title" class="flex-grow-1">
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <!-- Right -->
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <button class="nav-link">Preview</button>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <button class="nav-link">Publish</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </form>
    </div><!-- /.post-edit -->
    </main> <!-- /Main Container -->
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to extend your `input` width. So, add this to css.**

**Formula:** `width = 100% - (nav margin) - (ul margin);`

```
input {
 width: calc(100% - 15px - 1em); // 15px > nav-margin | 1em > ul margin
}
```

**Check the snippet**

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.post-edit .nav-header {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 40px;
}

.post-edit .nav-header ul li button {
  border: 1px solid #727272;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #727272;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 3.5px 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 5.3px;
}

input {
  width: calc(100% - 15px - 1em);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <!-- Main Container -->
    <main class="container-wrapper">

      <div class="post-edit">
        <form action="" method="post">
          <div class="nav-header navbar navbar-expand-sm">
            <!-- Left -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <input type="text" name="p-title" placeholder="Title">
              </li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Right -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <button class="nav-link">Preview</button>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <button class="nav-link">Publish</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
      </form>
  </div>
  <!-- /.post-edit -->
  </main>
  <!-- /Main Container -->
  </div>
</body>
```